# Does continue statement blocks the entire code below it, even if it is within if statement?

Tags: java

Here is my code.

```
    public class TwinPrimeNumbers {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            boolean isTwinPrime = false;
            int count = 0, countTwo = 0, countThree = 0;
            
            inner:
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                
                for (int j = 1; j <= ((i + 2) / 2); j++) { 
                    
                    if (i % j == 0) 
                        count++; 
                    
                    if ((i + 2) % j == 0)
                        countTwo++; // 1
                }
                
                if (count >= 1 || countTwo >= 1) { // This part is having a problem.
                    continue inner;
                }
    
                else {
                    
                    for (int j = 1; j <= ((i + 1) / 2); j++) {
                        
                        if ((i + 1) % j == 0) {
                            countThree++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                isTwinPrime = (i + 2) - i == 2;
    
                if ( isTwinPrime == true && countThree >= 2 && count == 1 && countTwo == 1)
                    System.out.printf("Twin Primes: ( %d, %d ) %n", i, (i + 2));
                count = 0;
                countTwo = 0;
                countThree = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm having a problem when this statement appear on my code There is no output appearing in the console.
Does the continue statement blocks the other code below?

```
**if (count >= 1 || countTwo >= 1) {
    continue inner;
}**
```

Because there is no output appearing when I run the program.

Comment: Because as far as I know the continue statement is valid but inside the loop with a if statement. Thank you for your answers <3

Comment: You've labelled your outer loop as `inner`. Is that correct?

Comment: There's no need to specifiy a label for the `continue`. The loop that will be `continue`d is the one (semantically incorrectly) labeled `inner`.

Comment: Don't! Please, don't use labels. They are pure evil.

Comment: Your if-logic is flawed. `count` and `countTwo` are initialzed at `0` and both raised to `1` before they reach the if. You also never decrease them so this if-statement is always true.

Comment: @Amongalen Not in all cases though. Break/continue inside a heavily nested loop is a valid use case, in which using labels makes code much clearer.

Comment: @Amongalen i disagree. It's very valid for `break`ing or `continue`ing specific loops.

Comment: @AndrewVershinin "inside a heavily nested loop" - then you should refactor it to not be heavily nested. Adding a label isn't the way of solving such problem. If you follow clean code guidelines then there is no room for labels.

Comment: I get the output when I remove the if that have continue statement. the code in the second for loop is determining if the two numbers are prime numbers

Comment: Also, the count and countTwo variables are only incremented if their condition is satisfied. so I am confused why are there is still no output even the condition in the if statement is satisfied.

Comment: Don't think you will get the correct output even if you remove the `continue` statement because there is `else` block with the `if `statement that contains the `continue` statement. `else` block is not executed because the `if` statement is executed in each iteration.

Comment: even if I change to > 1 the condition, it is still not working
I output trace the program and the count and countTwo variables are having correct value

even if it is value 1 I changed the conditiion from >= to > there is still no output

Answer (score 1):

`continue` statement skips the current iteration of the loop.

In your code, `count >= 1 || countTwo >= 1` is true for each value of `i`, so `continue` statement executes in each iteration of the outer loop and as soon as `continue` statement executes, it jumps back to the start of the loop without ever executing the statements below. Eventually, loop's termination condition evaluates to false and hence the loop breaks.

There is absolutely no use of label in your case because without label, your  code will execute in exactly the same manner as it is with the label.

Also your logic is all wrong. You can simplify your code as shown below:

```
public class TwinPrimeNumbers {
    static boolean isPrime(int n) { 
        if (n <= 1) return false; 
  
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) 
            if (n % i == 0) return false; 
  
        return true; 
    } 
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int primeOne = -1;
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            // if current number is prime and the differene between
            // previously saved prime number and current number is 2, 
            // then we have a pair of Twin Primes 
            if (i - primeOne == 2 && TwinPrimeNumbers.isPrime(i)) {
                System.out.printf("Twin Primes: ( %d, %d ) %n", primeOne, i);
                // update primeOne
                primeOne = i;
            }
            // if previous condition is false and current number is prime,
            // save it in primeOne variable 
            else if (TwinPrimeNumbers.isPrime(i)) {
                primeOne = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
Twin Primes: ( 3, 5 ) 
Twin Primes: ( 5, 7 ) 
Twin Primes: ( 11, 13 ) 
Twin Primes: ( 17, 19 ) 
Twin Primes: ( 29, 31 ) 
Twin Primes: ( 41, 43 ) 
Twin Primes: ( 59, 61 ) 
Twin Primes: ( 71, 73 )
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This helps a lot. In my case, the only problem on my code is the continue statement, whenever I removed that, I also get the same output.

Comment: `continue` statement is a problem in your code because it is executed in each iteration and that's because you are not incrementing or decrementing the values of `count` and `countTwo` variables correctly.

Comment: I output trace the code the value of count and countTwo is correct even if it is not greater than 1 it is still not delivering an output

Answer (score 0):

`continue inner` means to continue execution from the next iteration of the loop labeled `inner`, regardless of where this statement is (other than that it may appear only inside said loop).

Comment: even I remove the label, it still no output

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!

`continue`'s  use case as a `goto` is not really encouraged as it represents an unconditional jump through the code.

In this case you can discard the label considering your `continue` statement is not included in more than one loop. The code becomes:

```java
int count = 0, countTwo = 0, countThree = 0;
            
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
   for (int j = 1; j <= ((i + 2) / 2); j++) {     
       if (i % j == 0) 
          count++; 
                    
       if ((i + 2) % j == 0)
          countTwo++; // 1
   }
   
   if (count >= 1 || countTwo >= 1) { // This part is having a problem.
      continue;
   }

...
```

Comment: Even I remove the label, it still no output appearing in the console.